# Problems with default value of pointer to pointer in constructor

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

When we are using a "double" pointer to class, what are we writing in the constructor with arguments? Are we using one pointer for the allocated memory ?

Here is the code. It doesn't compile and I don't understand why. Thanks for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Article{
private:
    char title[100];
    char author[50];
    char *content;
    bool publish;
public:
    Article(char *title="", char *author="", char *content="", bool publish=0){
    strcpy(this->title, title);
    strcpy(this->author, author);
    this->content=new char[strlen(content)+1];
    strcpy(this->content, content);
    this->publish=publish;
    }
    void show(){
        cout<<title<<endl;
        cout<<author<<endl;
        cout<<content<endl;
    }
    ~Article(){
        delete [] content;
    }
};

class Newspaper{
private:
    char name[100];
    Article **p;
    int articles;
    Article first;
public:
    Newspaper(char *name="", Article **p=Article(), int articles=0, Article first=Article()){
        strcpy(this->name, name);
    }

};

int main() {
    char title[100], author[50], content[100];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char name[100];
    cin.getline(name, 100);
    cin.getline(name, 100);

    Article first("VAZNO","OOP","Vezba:OOP",true);
    Newspaper v(name,first);
    Article **s = new Article*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin.getline(title, 100);
        cin.getline(author, 50);
        cin.getline(content, 100);
        v.addArticle(Article(title, author, content, true)); //se koristi copy konstruktor
    }
    v.showFirst();
    v.showLongest();
    cout << v.totalofauthor(author) << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        delete s[i];
    }
    delete [] s;
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cy6p6Pf4 here's the code :)

Comment: Please create a minimal example from that code and put it in the question

Comment: You could probably solve all your bugs, and more you haven't found yet, if you just used `std::string` and `std::vector`

Comment: Your syntax in not correct:  `Article **p=Article()`.  You want one of these: `Article p = Article()` or `Article *p = new Article` or `Article * * p = 0`.  Prefer not to use dynamic memory, as memory management is difficult (when to delete the pointer, who owns the target, how many pointers point to the object, etc).

Comment: A _minimal_ example. Man, selective reading is all the rage these days!

Comment: It's very unclear what your code does, mainly because it is broken! You will have to explain your intentions.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution to your question:

From your code it seems that a `Newspaper` uses a pointer to a pointer (what you call a double pointer) for keeping track of the `Articles`:

```
    Newspaper(char *name, Article **p ,                       // This would be ok
                 int articles = 0, Article first = Article())
```

but that you've trouble to define a default argument for it:

```
    Newspaper(char *name="", Article **p=Article(),          // oops doesn't compile 
                 int articles = 0, Article first = Article())
```

The reason is that a "double" pointer is not the same as the object itself.  If you want a default argument here, you must provide a double pointer as well.

This code does exactly this:

```
    Newspaper(char *name = "", Article **p = new Article*,    // this is ok !
                 int articles = 0, Article first = Article()){
```

So this is the solution to your question.

## But what's your problem ?

But what's the purpose or providing a dummy pointer, pointing to nowhere as default argument ?

Later you try to create a `Newspaper` based on an article again:

```
    Newspaper v(name, first);   // won't work, because first is not a pointer either
```

So the problem is not the constructor, but the whole principle.  It seems that you really want to create a `Newspaper` based on an `Article`, and that you use defaults to cover the case where someone wants to create a  `Newspaper` without `Article`.

Apparently your design also foresees that `Articles` may be added dynamically:

```
    v.addArticle(Article(title, author, content, true));
```

Finally it seems that you really have a problem with pointers: when in the constructor you write, you didn't initialise the poitner to a memory region large enough to hold the name:

```
 Newspaper(char *name = "", ...) { 
    strcpy(this->name, name);    // Ouch !!  pointer name is not initalized !  
 }
```

So once you'll get your code compiled, your programme won't work ! As `this->name` is a pointner that is never initialized, your `strcpy()` will cause memory corruption and undefined behaviour (crash!?).

## Recommendations

First, get a book or a tutorial to understand and master pointers.  If you do'nt you'll quickly be completely lost in your C++ class.

In the meantime, get rid of your `char*` and `strcpy()` and alike, and use **[`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)** instead.

Last, consider the use of **[`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)** to manage the dynamic `Article` container.  A dynamic array of poitners implemented with `Article**` would need extra logic, such as maintaining the size, reallocation of memory once the number of article grows, not speaking of the ownership (allocation/deallocation) of the Articles you put in the array.

Based on these recommendations, your `Newspaper` would look like this:

```
class Newspaper{
private:
    string name;
    vector<Article> p;   // p.size() will provide the number of articles 

public:
    Newspaper(string name = "") : name(name) { }  // empty newspaper 
    Newspaper(string name, Article& a) : Newspaper(name) {  // combo
        addArticle(a); 
        }
    void addArticle(Article &a) {
        p.push_back(a);                // add and article to the vector
    }
    ... // rest of the code, here
};
```

And [here](http://goo.gl/yWbp4v) a little more